# Can typename be omitted in the type-specifier of an out of line member definition?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

I ran into this strange behaviour when testing whether or not `typename` is required by clang. Both clang and gcc accept this code while msvc rejects it.

```
template<class T1>
struct A
{
    template<class T2>
    struct B
    {
        static B f;
        static typename A<T2>::template B<T1> g;
    };
};

template<class T1>
template<class T2>
typename A<T2>::template B<T1> // ok, typename/template required
    A<T1>::B<T2>::g;

template<class T1>
template<class T2>
A<T1>::B<T2> // clang/gcc accept, msvc rejects missing typename
    A<T1>::B<T2>::f;
```

In general, a qualified-id `A<T1>::B<T2>` (where `A<T1>` is a dependent name) should be written `typename A<T1>::template B<T2>`. Is the behaviour of gcc/clang incorrect, or is there an exception to the general rule (quoted below) in this particular case?

It could be argued that `A<T1>` is not a dependent name, or that `B<T2>` refers to a member of the current instantiation. However, at the point of parsing the type-specifier it's not possible to know that the current instantiation is `A<T1>`. It seems problematic to require the implementation to guess that `A<T1>` is the current instantiation.

> 14.6 Name resolution [temp.res]
>
> A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is dependent on a template-parameter is
>   assumed not to name a type unless the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified
>   by the keyword typename.
>
> 14.2 Names of template specializations [temp.names]
>
> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a postfix-expression or after a
>   nested-name-specifier in a qualified-id, and the object or pointer expression of the postfix-expression or the
>   nested-name-specifier in the qualified-id depends on a template parameter (14.6.2) but does not refer to a
>   member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword
>   template. Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.

To further investigate what clang is doing here, I also tried this:

```
template<class T1>
struct C
{
    template<class T2>
    struct D
    {
        static typename A<T1>::template B<T2> f;
        static typename A<T1>::template B<T2> g;
    };
};

template<class T1>
template<class T2>
typename A<T1>::template B<T2> // ok, typename/template required
    C<T1>::D<T2>::f;

template<class T1>
template<class T2>
A<T1>::B<T2> // clang rejects with incorrect error
    C<T1>::D<T2>::g;
```

Clang gives `error: redefinition of 'g' with a different type`, but the type of `g` actually matches the declaration.

I would instead expect to see a diagnostic suggesting the use of `typename` or `template`.

This gives credit to the hypothesis that clang's behaviour in the first example is unintended.

Comment: I personally would add the `typename`... but don't have the drive to dig into the standard just now :)

Comment: @dribeas No worries ;). You must be tired of all these language lawyer questions by now!

Comment: Regardless of which is right or wrong, you deserve an upvote just for finding *any* code that gcc and clang accept, but VC++ rejects on the basis of a missing `typename`.

Answer (score 1):

clang and gcc are correct.

The compiler knows `A<T1>::B<T2>` refers to a type and `B<T2>` is a template and that `A<T1>::B<T2>::f` is a member of the current instantiation. Therefore, the `typename` and `template` keywords are not necessary.

From v14.6.2.1p4:

> A name is a member of the current instantiation if it is
>
> A qualified-id in which the nested-name-specifier refers to the
>   current instantiation and that, when looked up, refers to at least one
>   member of the current instantiation

`A<T1>::B<T2>` is a qualified-id and `A<T1>::` is the nested-name-specifier which refers to the current instantiation. We know that `A<T1>::` refers to the current instantiation from 14.6.2.1p1:

> A name refers to the current instantiation if it is
>
> — in **the definition of** a primary class template or **a member of a
>   primary class template**, **the name of the class template followed by the
>   template argument list of the primary template** (as described below)
>   enclosed in <> (or an equivalent template alias specialization),

In your code, we have a definition of a member of a primary class template, i.e. `A<T1>::B<T2>::f`, and `A<T1>` is the name of the class template followed by the template argument list of the primary template.

In your question, you say `However, at the point of parsing the type-specifier it's not possible to know that the current instantiation is A<T1>`. However, I cannot follow that because the name `A<T1>` does refer to the current instantiation as stated above.

Comment: The the rules that require `typename` (and `template`) make it possible for the parser to know whether a dependent name is a type or a template. The parser advances through a stream of tokens, and must make the decision about whether a name is a type (or a template) at the point at which a token is encountered. In order to decide whether `A<T1>::B` names a class template without the `typename` keyword, the parser would have to look ahead a (potentially unlimited) number of tokens to discover that `A<T1>` is the current instantiation.

Comment: @willj: While the first part of your comment is correct, the second is not. Certain forms of the name identify the current instantiation. In this case `A<T1>`, and `::A<T1>` both name the current instantiation. The compiler identifies the current instantiation by the syntax, see 14.6.2.1p3 for examples.

Comment: See [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3fe1c0107d63f27f28792d7678c32b3a-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336) and the error messages. The compiler **knows** `A<T1>::B` names a class template because it already looked it up.

Comment: If what you say is true, why doesn't this work as well? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4277b01cb1ba0829cc38bdfe0bc0d153-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51

Comment: You're asserting that `template<class T1> template<class T2> A<T1>` names the current instantiation, which seems to be the same assumption made by clang. What happens when this is immediately followed by `::B<T2> C<T1>::D<T2>::g` as in my second example? In this case clang breaks because the assumption that `A<T1>` names the current instantiation turned out to be incorrect.

Comment: @VaughnCato: Good question, I don't know the answer. [Take this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7e5cd6d2aae4ced66dc1d9c3c278bbca-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336), anywhere else except the return type does not require `typename`.

Comment: @JesseGood: There is a note in 14.6.2.1p4 of the C++11 standard which says "This can only occur when looking up a name in a scope enclosed by the definition of a class template".  The standard states that the scope of a class extends to the member definitions outside the class for the part that is after the declarator-id. (C++11 3.3.7p5).  Since the return type is specified before the declarator-id, it seems to me that the names used cannot be part of the current instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

MSVC is correct.

My reading of the C++11 standard suggests that `typename` is required.

Without the `typename` keyword, a dependent name is assumed not to name a type.

> 14.6 Name resolution [temp.res]
>
> 2)
>   A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is dependent on a template-parameter is
>   assumed not to name a type unless the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified
>   by the keyword typename.
>
> 3)
>   When a qualified-id is intended to refer to a type that is not a member of the current instantiation
>   and its nested-name-specifier refers to a dependent type, it shall be prefixed by the keyword typename
>
> 7)
>   Within the definition of a class template or *within the definition of a member of a class template following
>   the declarator-id*, the keyword typename is not required when referring to the name of a previously declared
>   member of the class template that declares a type. [Note: such names can be found using unqualified name
>   lookup, *class member lookup into the current instantiation*, or class member access
>   expression lookup when the type of the object expression is the current instantiation
>
> 14.6.2.1 Dependent types [temp.dep.type]
>
> A name refers to the *current instantiation* if it is
>
> - in the definition of a primary class template or a member of a primary class template, the name of the
>     class template followed by the template argument list of the primary template (as described below)
>     enclosed in <>

When `A<T1>` is used in the definition of a member of `A`, it refers to the *current instantiation*. When parsing the definition of `f` a type name qualified by `A<T1>::` can be found by *class member name lookup into the current instantiation*.

However, when the C++ parser encounters `A<T1>` in the return-type of a member function definition - before the declarator-id - it has not yet encountered the name of the enclosing class. The parser cannot determine whether or not `A` refers to the enclosing class at this point.

For this reason - regardless of whether or not `A<T1>` names the current instantiation - the standard does not permit omission of `typename` within the definition of a member of a class template before the declarator-id.

This [example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NrXfYV6FeTvCUGl9) by Vaughn Cato demonstrates that the behaviour of Clang/GCC is inconsistent, and requires `typename` in a similar scenario:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    typedef int X;
    X f();
};

template <typename T>
A<T>::X A<T>::f() // error: missing 'typename'
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Years later, C++20 renders this use of `typename` and `template` optional (although compilers aren’t done implementing the new rules).  It turned out that compilers had to do something like what GCC and Clang were already doing here to support out-of-line constructor definitions anyway.