# Template class with nested template class, g++ compiles fine, vs2013 wont compile

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2013, g++, nested-class

I'm implementing my own map and this is a piece of the code. A part of the code that is troubling me is these two declarations:

```
template<typename KEY, typename VAL>
Map<KEY,VAL>::MapPair<KEY,VAL> Map<KEY,VAL>::make_map_pair(KEY k, VAL v){
    return MapPair<KEY,VAL>(k,v);
 }

template<typename KEY, typename VAL>
template<typename K, typename V>
Map<KEY,VAL>::MapPair<K,V>& Map<KEY,VAL>::MapPair<K,V>::setKey(K keyp, V val){
    key = keyp;
    value = val;
 }
```

The class def is as follows:

```
 template <typename KEY, typename VAL>
 class Map{
 private:
    template<typename K, typename V>
    class MapPair {
    public:
        K key;
        V value;
        MapPair(){};
        MapPair(K key, V value);
        MapPair<K,V>& setKey(K key, V val);
        V& getValue();
        K getKey();
        bool operator==(MapPair<K,V> item);
    };

    List<MapPair<KEY,VAL>> pair_list_;
    MapPair<KEY,VAL> make_empty_map_pair(KEY k);
    MapPair<KEY,VAL> make_map_pair(KEY k, VAL v);
 public:
    Map(){}
    bool exists(KEY key);
    VAL& operator[](KEY key);
    VAL pop_pair(KEY key);
 };
```

This code compiles without a peep from g++, but Visual Studio 2013 flips out errors:

```
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

each of the top function definitions generate an error.

From g++ under debain 7.5

```
g++ -Wall -c -std=c++11  vm.cpp
g++ vm.o -o vm
```

and it runs nicely with no run time issues and does what its supposed to do.

The question is why does g++ run this fine, and vs2013 wont compile it?  What can I do to make this code compile properly on vs2013?  What kind of habits can I develop to ensure portability in the code that I write?

Comment: the return type of your functions sohuld be declared as `typename Map<KEY,VAL>::template MapPair<K,V>`

Comment: What exact version of g++ was used to compile this code?

Comment: This is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344580/can-typename-be-omitted-in-the-type-specifier-of-an-out-of-line-member-definitio .. which has not been conclusively answered

Answer (score 4):

So it turns out, VS2013 likes to have `typename` inserted before the return type of a nested class.  I knew I 'could' do that but id never know why I would until this instance.

```
template<typename KEY, typename VAL>
typename Map<KEY,VAL>::MapPair<KEY,VAL> Map<KEY,VAL>::make_map_pair(KEY k, VAL v){
/*^^^^^ right here before the nested class object that it will return.*/
    return MapPair<KEY,VAL>(k,v);
}
```

Best idea is to use it so the code can ported with less changes, even though g++ wont require it.

Comment: You're missing a `template`, should be `typename Map<KEY,VAL>::template MapPair<KEY,VAL>`

Answer (score 2):

My reading of the C++11 standard suggests that `typename` is required. VS2013 is doing the right thing.

Without the `typename` keyword, a dependent name is assumed not to name a type.

> 14.6 Name resolution [temp.res]
>
> 2)
>   A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is dependent on a template-parameter is
>   assumed not to name a type unless the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified
>   by the keyword typename.
>
> 3)
>   When a qualified-id is intended to refer to a type that is not a member of the current instantiation
>   and its nested-name-specifier refers to a dependent type, it shall be prefixed by the keyword typename
>
> 7)
>   Within the definition of a class template or *within the definition of a member of a class template following
>   the declarator-id*, the keyword typename is not required when referring to the name of a previously declared
>   member of the class template that declares a type. [Note: such names can be found using unqualified name
>   lookup, *class member lookup into the current instantiation*, or class member access
>   expression lookup when the type of the object expression is the current instantiation
>
> 14.6.2.1 Dependent types [temp.dep.type]
>
> A name refers to the *current instantiation* if it is
>
> - in the definition of a primary class template or a member of a primary class template, the name of the
>     class template followed by the template argument list of the primary template (as described below)
>     enclosed in <>

When `Map<KEY, VAL>` is used in the definition of `Map`, it refers to the *current instantiation*. When parsing the definition of `make_map_pair` a type name qualified by `Map<KEY, VAL>::` can in general be found by *class member name lookup into the current instantiation*.

However, when the C++ parser encounters `Map<KEY, VAL>` in the return-type of a member function definition - before the declarator-id - it has not yet encountered the name of the enclosing class. The parser cannot determine whether or not `Map` refers to the enclosing class at this point.

For this reason - regardless of whether or not `Map<KEY, VAL>` names the current instantiation - the standard does not permit omission of `typename` within the definition of a member of a class template before the declarator-id.

This [example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NrXfYV6FeTvCUGl9) by Vaughn Cato demonstrates that the behaviour of Clang/GCC is inconsistent, and requires `typename` in a similar scenario:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    typedef int X;
    X f();
};

template <typename T>
A<T>::X A<T>::f() // error: missing 'typename'
{
}
```

If we conclude that the name `Map` is dependent and `typename` is required then the `template` keyword is also required:

> 14.2 Names of template specializations [temp.names]
>
> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a postfix-expression or after a
>   nested-name-specifier in a qualified-id, and the object or pointer expression of the postfix-expression or the
>   nested-name-specifier in the qualified-id depends on a template parameter (14.6.2) but does not refer to a
>   member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword
>   template. Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.

The corrected example would be:

```
template<typename KEY, typename VAL>
typename Map<KEY,VAL>::template MapPair<KEY,VAL>
    Map<KEY,VAL>::make_map_pair(KEY k, VAL v) {
    return MapPair<KEY,VAL>(k,v);
}
```

There was a discussion of the same issue here: [Can typename be omitted in the type-specifier of an out of line member definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344580/can-typename-be-omitted-in-the-type-specifier-of-an-out-of-line-member-definitio)