# Template and typename keywords on out-of-class definition of nested template: VS 2012 and g++ 4.8.1 apparently disagree

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012, typename, g++4.8

I am currently trying to implement iterators for a custom templated container class following the approach outlined by [Dr.Dobb's](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-defining-iterato/184401331). It is working fine up to the point at which I am trying to define the iterator member functions for the nested Iterator

```
template <typename T>
class Container
{
  template <bool isConst = false>
  class Iterator
  {
    Iterator& operator++();
    Iterator  operator++(int);  
  };
};
```

out-of-class like this:

```
template <typename T>
template <bool isConst>
//Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>& // g++ 4.8.1 is fine with that
typename Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>& // VS 2012 is fine with that
//typename Container<T>::template Iterator<isConst>& // again fine with g++
  Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>::operator++()
{
  ++index_;

  return *this;
}

template <typename T>
template <bool isConst>
//Container<T>::Iterator<isConst> // g++ 4.8.1 is fine with that
typename Container<T>::Iterator<isConst> // VS 2012 is fine with that
//typename Container<T>::template Iterator<isConst> // again fine with g++
  Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>::operator++(int)
{
  auto tmp(*this);

  this->operator++();

  return tmp;
}
```

So far I have been able to identify the three different variants indicated (elaborated on below), which will work with either g++ 4.8.1 (with C++0x) or Visual Studio 2012 (Update 4), but not with both at the same time.

What is the correct way to do this?

There appears to be a somewhat [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484885/strange-vc-compile-error-c2244) from 2009, but as far as I can tell, it does not contain *Variant 4*, and I would assume compiler bugs to be fixed by now. ;)

And there is also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344580/can-typename-be-omitted-in-the-type-specifier-of-an-out-of-line-member-definitio), which makes me think that *Variant 3* should be the one, and the acceptance of *Variant 1* by g++ is a courtesy.

I have included my complete stripped-down test application at the bottom; it should compile as provided (with the appropriate lines commented).

### Variant 1: no keywords

```
Container<T>::Iterator<isConst> // g++ 4.8.1 is fine with that
```

For this variant, VS complains that a dependent name is not a type and suggests using the *typename* keyword:

```
2>..\demo\demo.cpp(70): warning C4346: 'Container<T>::?$Iterator@$Q_N(*(_CAAB@))' : dependent name is not a type  
2>          prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type  
2>..\demo\demo.cpp(70): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'  
2>..\demo\demo.cpp(70): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int  
2>..\demo\demo.cpp(70): error C2936: 'Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>' : template-class-id redefined as a global data variable  
2>..\demo\demo.cpp(70): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

### Variant 2: only *typename* keyword

```
typename Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>& // VS 2012 is fine with that
```

If just the *typename* keyword is used (as suggested by VS for Variant 1), g++ is not too happy about it:

```
main.cpp:71:28: error: non-template 'Iterator' used as template                                                      
     typename Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>& // VS 2012 is fine with that  
                            ^                           
main.cpp:71:28: note: use 'Container<T>::template Iterator' to indicate that it is a template                        
main.cpp:71:28: error: expected unqualified-id at end of input
```

### Variant 3: both keywords

```
typename Container<T>::template Iterator<isConst>& // again fine with g++
```

If both keywords are used (as suggested by g++ for Variant 2), VS is complaining again:

```
2>..\demo\demo.cpp(78): error C2244: 'Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>::operator ++' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration  
2>          definition  
2>          'Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>  &Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>::operator ++(void)'  
2>          existing declarations  
2>          'Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>  Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>::operator ++(int)'  
2>          'Container<T>::Iterator<isConst> &Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>::operator ++(void)'  
2>..\demo\demo.cpp(92): error C2244: 'Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>::operator ++' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration  
2>          definition  
2>          'Container<T>::Iterator<isConst> Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>::operator ++(int)'  
2>          existing declarations  
2>          'Container<T>::Iterator<isConst> Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>::operator ++(int)'  
2>          'Container<T>::Iterator<isConst> &Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>::operator ++(void)'
```

### Complete test application

Requires **-std=c++0x** with g++ because of the **auto** keyword.

```
template <bool isConst, typename IsTrue, typename IsFalse>
struct Choose;

template <typename IsTrue, typename IsFalse>
struct Choose<true, IsTrue, IsFalse>
{
  typedef IsTrue type;
};

template <typename IsTrue, typename IsFalse>
struct Choose<false, IsTrue, IsFalse>
{
  typedef IsFalse type;
};

template <typename T>
class Container
{
public:
  template <bool isConst = false>
  class Iterator
  {
  public:
    typedef typename Choose<isConst, T const&, T&>::type reference;
    typedef typename Choose<isConst, T const*, T*>::type pointer;

    typedef typename Choose<isConst,
      Container<T> const*,
      Container<T>*>::type ObjectPointer;

    friend class Iterator<true>;

    Iterator(
      ObjectPointer object           = 0,
      unsigned long long const index = 0);

    Iterator(Iterator<false> const& other);

    Iterator& operator++();
    Iterator  operator++(int);  

  private:
    ObjectPointer object_;

    unsigned long long index_;
  };

  typedef Iterator<>           iterator;
  typedef Iterator<true> const_iterator;
};

template <typename T>
template <bool isConst>
Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>::Iterator(
  ObjectPointer object,
  unsigned long long const index)
  : object_(object)
  , index_ (index )
{}

template <typename T>
template <bool isConst>
Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>::Iterator(Iterator<false> const& other)
  : object_(other.object_)
  , index_ (other.index_ )
{}

template <typename T>
template <bool isConst>
//Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>& // g++ 4.8.1 is fine with that
typename Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>& // VS 2012 is fine with that
//typename Container<T>::template Iterator<isConst>& // again fine with g++
  Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>::operator++()
{
  ++index_;

  return *this;
}

template <typename T>
template <bool isConst>
//Container<T>::Iterator<isConst> // g++ 4.8.1 is fine with that
typename Container<T>::Iterator<isConst> // VS 2012 is fine with that
//typename Container<T>::template Iterator<isConst> // again fine with g++
  Container<T>::Iterator<isConst>::operator++(int)
{
  auto tmp(*this);

  this->operator++();

  return tmp;
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
  Container<int> c;

  Container<int>::iterator it(&c, 0);

  Container<int>::const_iterator cIt = it;

  Container<int>::const_iterator cIt0 = ++cIt;
  Container<int>::const_iterator cIt1 = cIt++;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like this is in fact a VS2012 bug - I'm linking to the dup.

Comment: Thanks for the link - that question didn't come up in my research! In-class definition it is, I suppose...